# Скрыть блок div по клику

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно чтоб при нажатии одной ссылки закрывалась предыдущая. Не могу разобраться

```js
function toggle(imgElem, divId) {

  if(document.getElementById) {

    var divElem = document.getElementById(divId);

    if(divElem.className == "closed") {
        divElem.className = "opened";
        document.getElementById("linkname").InnerText = 'КНОПКА';

    } else {
        divElem.className = "closed";
        document.getElementById("linkname").InnerText = 'КНОПКА';

    }

  }

}
```

```css
.closed {display:none;}
.opened {display:block;}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="linkname" onclick="toggle(this,'openbox')">КНОПКА</a>

<div id="openbox" class="closed">
Text1
</div>


<a href="#" id="linkname" onclick="toggle(this,'openbox2')">КНОПКА</a>

<div id="openbox2" class="closed">
Text2
</div>
```

Comment: [Создание табов на чистом Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559387/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.view-source .hide').hide();
  $a = $('.view-source a');
  $a.on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $a.not(this).next().slideUp(500);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-source">
  <a href="#">111</a>
  <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>
<div class="view-source">
  <a href="#">222</a>
  <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>
<div class="view-source">
  <a href="#">333</a>
  <div class="hide">Спрятанный текст</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

А чем вам JQuery не угодил?

```js
function toggle(divId) {

  if(document.getElementById) {

    var divElem = document.getElementById(divId);
    // нужно открыть или закрыть?
    var opened = divElem.classList.contains("opened");
    
    var openbox_elems = document.getElementsByClassName('openbox-elem');
    for(var i=0; i<openbox_elems.length; i++){
        // закрываем все табы
        openbox_elems[i].classList.remove('opened');
    }
    if(!opened){
       // нужный был закрыт, открываем
       divElem.classList.add('opened'); 
    }

  }

}
```

```css
.closed {display:none;}
.opened {display:block;}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="linkname" onclick="toggle('openbox')">КНОПКА</a>

<div id="openbox" class="closed openbox-elem">
Text1
</div>


<a href="#" id="linkname" onclick="toggle('openbox2')">КНОПКА</a>

<div id="openbox2" class="closed openbox-elem">
Text2
</div>
```