# Как сделать переключение вкладок с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как создать страницу с переключением вкладок по нажатию на заголовок вкладки? Разные вкладки - разное содержимое. Нужно сделать подсветку активной вкладки.

На чистом JavaScript и CSS. Без JQuery и Bootstrap.

Comment: вот пару примеров css и javascript https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: Что не получается?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Создание табов на чистом Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/559387/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Можно вообще без javascript обойтись.

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/v6xqv5y3/

css:

```
.tabs_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 400px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.hide, .tab_content {
    display:none;
}
.hide + label {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
    padding:0.25em 1em;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:grey; 
    color :#fff;
    order:0;
    margin:0 5px -1px 0;
}
.hide:checked + label {
    background-color :#fff;
    color:#000;
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
}
.tab_content {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    padding:1em;
}
.hide:checked + label + .tab_content {
    display:block;
    order:1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs_container">
    <input class="hide" type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1"/>
    <label for="tab1">Вкладка 1</label>
    <div class="tab_content" id="tab_content_1">Содержимое вкладки 1</div>

    <input class="hide" type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab2"/>
    <label for="tab2">Вкладка 2</label>
    <div class="tab_content" id="tab_content_2">Содержимое вкладки 2</div>

    <input class="hide" type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3"/>
    <label for="tab3">Вкладка 3</label>
    <div class="tab_content" id="tab_content_3">Содержимое вкладки 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: хороший подход ! я тоже так делал раньше

Comment: А теперь почему перестал? =)

Comment: есть проще методы ... js jquery и т д

Comment: JS проще? я бы поспорил. По производительности так гораздо хуже для системы. А совать монструозный jQuery в сайт ради переключения вкладочек - вообще фейспалм.жпг...

Comment: я не буду спорить - но jQuery занимается не только переключением вкладочек, тот же ru.stackoverflow, google,twitter и прочие известные ресурсы что бы система не тормозила хранят jQuery у себя на хостинге а не берут ссылку с cdn , и потом 99% сайтов используют ajax а это тоже jQuery и конечно я не буду утверждать что jq это хорошо но и не плохо ...я до сиих пор не увидел плохого ни чего ... к примеру скажите что в нём плохого ?и назовите мне ту технологию которая хорошая !

Comment: Не, я ж не возражаю - если на сайте уже активно используется жквери, то логично заюзать его и для вкладочек. Но если речь о каком-нибудь сайте-визитке или чем-то легком, где жквери еще нет - логичнее его и не брать.   А что плохого? Как бы так помягче выразиться... КПД у него хреновый, вот. А "технология, которая хорошая" - не использовать яваскрипт ,если его можно не использовать. CSS отработает на порядок прозводительнее, а то и не на один.

Comment: ну так то да ... но мы же идём в ногу со временем .. используем всякие  vue ,angular и тому подобные техники .. щас уже ни кого не удивишь отличным знанием css3, щас уже анимируют SVG что на css не сделать кросбраузерно, в моде паралакс .. при чём сложный, всякие выпадашки и анимации ...а это тоже jQuery, мы же не будем велосипедить и изобретать новую технологию которая всё это сделает ...на vue и т д эта хренотень велосипедится долго а на jQuery час максимум ..я не знаю ещё доводов...на любой плюс всегда есть два минуса